# Should I define dependable variable in the body of the react component or in the useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider we have a component and inside there is some child

```
const Component = () => {
 const someValue = useSelector(state => state.someReducer);
 const someValue1 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer1);
 const someValue2 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer2);

 return (
       <>
         {someValue && someValue1 && someValue2 && <Child/>}
       </>
     )  
    }
```

And this is bad cause of too long condition in the render. I decided to move it into the variable. I could define condition in the body

```
const Component = () => {

 const someValue = useSelector(state => state.someReducer);
 const someValue1 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer1);
 const someValue2 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer2);

 const condition  = someValue && someValue1 && someValue2;

 return (    <>
     {condition && <Child/>}    </>  ) 
  }
```

Or I could use useEffect hook and

```
const Component = () => {

 const someValue = useSelector(state => state.someReducer);
 const someValue1 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer1);
 const someValue2 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer2);

 const [condition, setCondition]  = useState(false);

 useEffect = () => {

   setCondition(someValue && someValue1 && someValue2);

 }, [someValue, someValue1, someValue2]);

return ( 
  <>
     {condition && <Child/>}   
  </>  )

}
```

They say

> By using  useEffect, you tell React that your component needs to do
> something after render. React will remember the function you passed
> (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after
> performing the DOM updates.

But we update component if state or props changes - in our case Redux state, so in our condition variable there always be "fresh" data.

Usually in my everyday life I initialize the variable in the "body" of the component. But after several years I started to question myself: am I doing right? What is the rightest approach in React way?

Comment: If the answer bellow helped, consider mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since `useSelector` values are already memoized. Your first and second approaches are good while the third one will create a useless re-render.

The question here is about readability more than performance:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const someValue = useSelector(state => state.someReducer);
  const someValue1 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer1);
  const someValue2 = useSelector(state => state.someReducer2);

  if(!someValue || !someValue1 || !someValue2) return null

  return <Child/>
}
```